# rawlist function hangs for hours and never completes on large folder

Tags: phpseclib

I am retrieving a list of files in a folder with tens of thousands of files. I've let the script execute for a few hours but it never seems to progress after this part. Is there a way to diagnose what's going on or the progress of the list? It used to take a few minutes to load the list, so I am not sure why it's all of a sudden hanging now.

### Code

```
function EchoDump($echoOut = 0)
{
    if($echoOut)
        echo str_repeat("<!-- Agent Smith -->", 1000);
    else
        return str_repeat("<!-- Agent Smith -->", 1000);
}

$sftp_connection = new Net_SFTP($website ,2222);
$login_result = $sftp_connection->login($credentials->login(), $credentials->password());

echo "<pre>Login Status: ".( $login_result ? "Success" :  "Failure") ."</pre>";

if($sftp_connection->chdir($photosFolder))
    echo "<pre>Changed to $photosFolder</pre>";
else
{
    echo "<pre>Failed to change to $photosFolder</pre>";
}

echo "<pre>Downloading List.</pre>";
EchoDump(1);
$rawlist = $sftp_connection->rawlist();
echo "<pre>List downloaded.</pre>";
EchoDump(1);
```

### Output

*Login Status: Success

Changed to /vspfiles/photos

Downloading List.*

And then it will just sit with *Downloading List* as the last output forever.

Answer (score 0):

Real time logging might help provide some insight. You can enable that by adding `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 3);` to the top of your script. Once you got that maybe post it on pastebin.org for dissection.

That said, I will say that `rawlist()` doesn't return directory info on demand. It'll return everything. It's not the most efficient of designs but back in phpseclib 1.0 days Iterators didn't exist. phpseclib works with PHP4 so it had to work with what it had. The current master branch requires PHP 5.6 and is under active development so maybe this behavior will change but we'll see.

Comment: Is there any way possible to make rawlist() list the files based on a search expression? i.e: `ls a*` to list all files beginning with a. My goal is to get the dates and file sizes of the remote directory to make a 1 to 1 parity on a local directory.

Comment: @JackCole - You're best bet for doing `ls a*` would be to do `$ssh->exec()`. SFTP as a protocol doesn't support pattern searches in directory listings: https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-13#section-8.2.2 Certainly it'd be possible to emulate it but it'd require emulation. That said, if you can't do `$ssh->exec()` you might have more success with `nlist()`. `rawlist()` returns file attributes - `nlist()` doesn't so the `nlist()` responses would be significantly smaller and thus faster to parse.